# Optimize the contractivity of a self-adjoint operator on a closed subspace

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, self-adjoint-operators

Let $H$ be a $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space and $A\in\mathfrak L(H)$ be self-adjoint with $$\left\|Ax\right\|_H\le\left\|x\right\|_H\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in H.\tag1$$

> Let $K\subseteq H$ be closed and suppose I want to show that $$\left\|Ax\right\|_H\le c\left\|x\right\|_H\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in K\tag2$$ for some $c\in[0,1)$. Now assume that I'm able to minimize $\sup_{x\in K}\langle Ax,x\rangle_H$. Are we able to relate the obtained bound to $c$?

Comment: If $C$ is a linear subspace, then the sup is either $\le0$.

Comment: @daw $C=K$, sorry.

Comment: $K$ is assumed to be a closed subspace? Also $A=-I$ is a counterexample: the sup is $0$ (as small as it can get), still (2) is violated.

Comment: @daw But $$\sup_{\substack{x,\:y\:\in\:H\\\left\|x\right\|_H,\:\left\|y\right\|_H\:\le\:1}}\left|\langle Ax,y\rangle_H\right|=\sup_{x\:\in\:H\setminus\left\{0\right\}}\frac{\left|\langle Ax,x\rangle_{L^2(\mu)}\right|}{\left\|x\right\|_H^2}=\left\|A\right\|_{\mathfrak L(H)}\le1\tag3.$$ Now, if $H$ is a $L^2$-space, $A$ is nonnegativity-preserving and $f,g\in L^2$ are nonnegative, are we able to show that $\langle Af,g\rangle_{L^2}\le\langle f,g\rangle_{L^2}$?